# New error Cannot parse regular expression: expected ')' with Xcode 14

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Just updated to Xcode 14 and now running into these new parsing errors:
|
[Xcode 14 parsing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9ZPH.png)

I am gettin:

```
Cannot parse regular expression: expected ')'
```

for lines of code such as:

```
let cost = (/Float(/localPrice) / /Float(/self.weight)).twoDigitPrecision()
```

and

```
let y = round(100.0 * /Float(/self.costPerUnit)) / 100.0
```

This code never gave me this error until updating.
I can easily fix this code by removing the "/" and safely unwrapping, but why did this happen and is there an easy way to resolve all of these new errors?

Thank you

Comment: In Swift 5.7 a (forward) slash indicates a [Regular Expression](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/getting-started-with-swift-regex/) pattern.

Comment: @vadian thank you so am I ok manually correcting these pattens by removing the forward slash?

Comment: I think so. I'm wondering anyway what this slash stands for?